# Способ подтверждения email'a при регистрации (использую Selenium Webdriver)

Tags: python, selenium

Привет.

Есть скрипт на Python. Он осуществляет простую регистрацию на одном веб-сайте.

Но после регистрации необходимо вручную заходить на почту (Outlook) и кликать на confirmation link.

Может есть какой-то способ, идея это все автоматизировать?

ПС. Рассматривал вариант с отсылкой, например, на Гмейл, потом заходом на гмейл через браузер, выбор нужного письма, и клика по урлу. Но может есть более изысканный способ?

Answer (score 1):

Поднять питоновый SMTP сервер ([типа такого](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/smtpd/)) и принимать почту на него. Т.е. купить домен, у него прописать в dns MX со своим SMTP сервером и указывать мыло на этом сервере при регистрации. Скрипт будет получать почту и ходить по ссылкам в письмах…

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего пользоваться сервисами типа mailinator, там ящик доступен просто по прямой ссылке (без логина и пароля).

Answer (score 1):

Я использую mailforspam для тестирования в своих проектах. Меня полностю устраивает.

Answer (score -1):

Проще всего ознакомиться с API GMail, создать там почту, отправлять на неё письма, потом подконектитсья и считать последнее письмо

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score -1):

Вот почти готовый авторег для любых сайтов, только сам не могу понять, как массово сделать и почему не работает код в 3.6, а в 2.7 должен работать.
[Как подтвердить почту при регистрации на пайтон?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1256431/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd)